# How to color matching parenthesis within listings?

Tags: color, listings

What I would like to achieve are rainbow-colored parenthesis (just like [Rainbow delimeters in 
Emacs](https://github.com/Fanael/rainbow-delimiters)) based on their depth in a newly defined style for a programming language (Racket). For example:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))
```

where the two outermost brackets are maybe red and the 4 inner ones green (and if there were deeper pairs of parthesis, they would be yellow, cyan, pink etc.).

Trying to write something like

```
\textcolor{red}{(} blabla \textcolor{red}{)}
```

is on the one hand tideous, on the other hand unuseable within `lstlisting` with `mathescape=true` enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I start with experimenting with following macro

```
\newcount\bralevel

\def\colorizebrackets{\bgroup \catcode`\ =13 \colbraA}
\def\colbraA#1{\egroup \bralevel=0 \edef\colorizedtext{\colbraB #1{}}}
\def\colbraB#1{\ifx\relax#1\relax \else
   \ifx(#1\colbraC{#1}\else
   \ifx)#1\colbraD{#1}\else 
   #1\fi\fi \expandafter\colbraB\fi}
\def\colbraC{\immediateassignment\advance\bralevel by1 \colbraE}
\def\colbraD#1{\colbraE{#1}\immediateassignment\advance\bralevel by-1 }
\def\colbraE{\csname colbra:\the\bralevel\endcsname}
\def\declcolbra#1#2{\protected\expandafter\def\csname colbra:#1\endcsname##1{#2}}
\bgroup \lccode`~=` \lowercase{\egroup \def~{ }}

\declcolbra 1{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\declcolbra 2{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
\declcolbra 3{\textcolor{yellow}{#1}}
\declcolbra 4{\textcolor{cyan}{#1}}
\declcolbra 5{\textcolor{pink}{#1}}

% test:

\colorizebrackets{(define (square x) (* x x))}
\colorizedtext

\show\colorizedtext
```

I tried this in LuaTeX: it knows the primitive `\immediateassignment` which makes the following `\advance` expandable. So, the core of the macro `\colbraB` is fully expandable. It can be used in another context where we need to use expandable macros. I used it by `\edef\colorizedtext{\colbraB#1{}}`. If you are not using LuaTeX then you can partially add the tokens to the `\colorizedtext` macro and the macro will be not expandable.

Comment: I'm not a macro-expert, could you maybe tell me what I'm doing wrong? I inserted your macro then `\colorizebrackets{(define (square x) (* x x))}` into my block of `lstlisting`. When I compile it with pdfLaTeX I get no colored parenthesis but literally the text `\colorizebrackets{(define (square x) (* x x))}`. 
If I add `\colorizebrackets{(define (square x) (* x x))}
\colorizedtext
\show\colorizedtext` outside of `lstlisting`, I get an undefined control sequence error.

Comment: I'm not latex-expert, so I don't know what `lstlisting` is. And I don't want to dive to macro details of such package. I have only shown that your question is solvable. My macro is only an example that it is possible, but it can be used only for testing and as standalone (with no cooperation with any LaTeX package).

Comment: Ok well, then to next question I guess :)